# Average Value of a Function

Tags: calculus

This is from Apostol's Calculus pg. 119 exercise 15, which I have been working on.

Let $$A_a^b(f) = \frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b f(x) dx \;, \text{which is the average value of}\,\, f \; \text{over} \; [a,b]$$

The exercise is to prove that there exists $t$ satisfying $0 <t<1$ such that

$$A_a^b(f)= t\:A_a^c(f)+(1-t)\:A_c^b(f)$$

What I have tried:

I first tried to write the equality out as integrals and then find a common factor that would allow me to combine the two integrals on the RHS into the integral on the LHS. Been working at that for quite a while with no progress. Then, I drew a diagram and tried to get a geometric understanding. That has helped a little because I can see that the factors $t$ and $t-1$ ,as $t$ varies from $0$ to $1$, trace out a line from $A_c^b(f)$ to $A_a^c(f)$. I haven't been able to make any connections otherwise. I have also tried to look for similar problems on this website and can't find any that help.

Thanks in advance for any tips you can give me.

**Edit:**
I forgot to mention that $a<c<b$

Comment: You mean for any $c$, right?

Comment: Yes, I mean with $a<c<b$

Comment: Think about a weighted average

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\textbf{Hint:}$
You want to find a value of $t$ so that

$\displaystyle\int_a^b f(x)dx=t\left(\frac{b-a}{c-a}\right)\int_a^c f(x)dx+(1-t)\left(\frac{b-a}{b-c}\right)\int_c^b f(x)dx$,

and you know that $\displaystyle\int_a^b f(x)dx=\int_a^c f(x)dx+\int_c^b f(x)dx$

Comment: I was able to find the solution $ t = \frac{c-a}{b-a}$ algebraically. However, is there any way to think about the problem that gets at the solution more intuitively? If this is too-soft of a question, and I should be happy to have any solution, then please ignore it.

Comment: @j.d.allen  I think the intuitive idea behind this is that the average on the entire interval must be between the averages on the two subintervals (since it can't be greater than, or less than, both of them); and if $u\le v\le w$, then $v=tu+(1-t)w$ for some $t$.